# Why do Desmond and Molly Jones switch roles in the repeated final verse of Ob-La-Di Ob-La-Da?

Tags: lyrics, meaning, the-beatles

In The Beatles' song *Ob-La-Di Ob-La-Da*, the last two verses are essentially the same except Desmond and Molly Jones switch actions. I've included a line by line comparison below with the differences emphasized.

#### Line by line comparison

> Happy ever after in the market place
>   *Happy ever after in the market place*
>
> **Desmond** lets the children lend a hand
>   ***Molly*** lets the children lend a hand
>
> **Molly** stays at home and does **her** pretty face
>   ***Desmond** stays at home and does **his** pretty face*
>
> And in the evening she's a singer with the band
>   *And in the evening she's a singer with the band*

What is the reason for this switch? Was it a flub by Paul?

Answer (score 5):

> Was it a flub by Paul?

Yes, Wikipedia cites the book "A Hard Day's Write" (Steve Turner) as claiming that this was initially a mistake by Paul, that was kept only because the other Beatles liked it.

But I have my doubts about that. Maybe Paul was an activist for emancipation and equal rights.

Comment: I've always thought the band were messing around with the song (the recording has quite a party vibe) and thought it would be fun  to turn things round at the end, but who knows? Just my opinion...

Comment: lala how the life goes on ... ;)

Comment: I have the cited book, can confirm that Wikipedia conveyed it accurately. The Beatles were characteristically playful in the studio, and often incorporated "happy accidents."  In this case, I think it improves the song, otherwise it's both repetitive and sexist. // In an interesting side note, the same source mentions that the song's odd chorus was stolen from a Nigerian friend of Paul's, Jimmy Scott -- Paul later "paid" for the theft by paying off Scott's legal debts on an unrelated case.

Answer (score 1):

There's footage of them recording and Paul realizes he mixed the lyrics up. The others suggest keeping it that way, and there it is. No such thing as a mistake when it comes to creating art. Unless you feel Picasso just kept screwing up his portraits.

Comment: Where can one find this footage?